# Apache: Load balancing by session

Tags: apache, tomcat, server, config, mod-jk

I have two backend servers (so 2 workers) and I load balance between them by session. But there is a problem: Once I load my app, it sends mulitple requests and the load balancer choses first worker AND it sends a single request to the second worker (for check?), so the jk-status will always put 1 session into the first worker and to the second and when I load the app on different browser (different session) the loadbalancer will always chose the first worker, because the number of sessions in both workers is the same. What to do?

I use Apache 2.2, Tomcat 8.5.x and mod_jk 1.2.40

workers.properties config:

```
worker.list=jkstatus,router
worker.jkstatus.type=status
worker.router.type=lb
worker.router.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
worker.router.method=S
worker.router.sticky_session=true
worker.template.type=ajp13
worker.template.lbfactor=1
worker.template.socket_keepalive=true
worker.template.recovery_options=7
worker.worker1.reference=worker.template
worker.worker1.host=mysite.com
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.redirect=worker2
worker.worker2.reference=worker.template
worker.worker2.host=mysecondsite.com
worker.worker2.port=8009
worker.worker2.redirect=worker1
```

Answer (score 0):

A certain situation forced me to switch from workers.properties to httpd.conf and use Proxy and Balancers (also updated Apache and mod_jk) and everything works great.